# Adding 10 whitespace characters using sed

Tags: linux, sed, freebsd, replace, whitespace

I have written a script that replaces a string, but I need to add the 10 whitespace characters back. I *can* add it back by pressing space 10 times, and that works, but this looks hideous in my script.

My script:
`sed -i 's/server.os[ \t]*$freebsd/server.os $linux/g' ~/var/log.txt`

I would like to add the 10 whitespace characters between `server.os` and `$linux` using something like `{whitespace*10}`

Note:

- There are 10 whitespace characters in front of `$freebsd` which is why I use `[ \t]*`
- `$` is not a variable in this case. It's just part of the string.

Sample input:
`server.os          $freebsd`

Desired output:
`server.os          $linux`

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Do you want to add 10 spaces, or do you want to add the _exact_ whitespace you had? Your regex will match spaces and tabs, don't you want to keep the tabs?

Comment: @terdon Sure, keeping the exact whitespace would be nice, but I don't understand the second part of your question.

Comment: @terdon OP already answered by his sample input

Comment: Damn it, it changed it right now with 3 answers :/

Comment: While both GNU and FreeBSD `sed` support a `-i` option, they added them independently around the same time with incompatible syntax. in FreeBSD `sed`, you need `sed -i ''` and in GNU `sed` `sed -i`. Also `[ \t]` matches either space or backslash or `t` in standard compliant `sed`s (for GNU `sed` only when a POSIXLY_CORRECT variable is in the environment)

Comment: @user898458 I meant that `[ \t]`, in GNU `sed` which is probably what you are using, means "0 or more spaces OR tab characters" but I suspect you think `[ \t]` means "10 spaces" somehow. A tab isn't a bunch of spaces, it is a completely different character.

Comment: @terdon Correct, I use GNU `sed`. As for spaces vs tabs, I have it set up in vim that a tab is equal to 4 spaces. That's why I use `[ \t]`.

Comment: @user898458 no, that's not how it works. Vim is _displaying_ a tab as 4 spaces, but what you have is still a single `\t` character and not 4 space characters. You can use `od -c < file` to see the actual characters in your file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture whatever(*ten, more, less or none*) continuous spaces and tabs you have in the original string in a group `([ \t])` ... Then put it back in the substitution string by its escaped reference number `\1` in this case like so:

```
sed -E 's/server\.os([ \t]*)\$freebsd/server.os\1$linux/g'
```

Notice: you need to escape the `.` and `$` as everything on the left hand is considered a regular expression.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer, as it is the simplest to understand and is the easiest to read. It also does not have the unintended effect where it erases everything on the same line, after the replaced string, like some of the other solutions.

Comment: @user898458 to avoid that, please make sure to show an _accurate_ input example. There was nothing else on the line in the example you gave so people had no way of knowing.

Comment: @terdon My apologies. I did not expect any other strings, after the replaced string would be removed. I have not seen this behaviour from `sed` before.

Answer (score 2):

### If you need to capture the already existing white spaces (new use-case):

```
$ sed 's/\(server.os[ \t]*\$\)freebsd/\1linux/' file
server.os          $linux
```

### If instead you need to create spaces that is not existing (old use-case):

##### Input file:

```
$ cat file
server.os $freebsd
```

##### With GNU `sed` as requested:

[At your own risks.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/743204/adding-10-whitespace-characters-using-sed/743205?noredirect=1#comment1412845_743205)

```
sed -E 's/(server\.os[ \t]*\$)freebsd.*/printf "%s%10s" \1 linux/e' file
```

##### With `Perl`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(server\.os)[ \t]*\$freebsd.*/$1 . " " x 10 . "linux"/e' file
server.os           $linux
```

If you use `-i`, it behave like `sed -i`: it replace *in line*.

##### The replacement part works like this:

1. `$1` captured group from the left regex with ( ... )
2. `.` concatenation
3. `" "` a literal space
4. `x 10` multiplication (10-times)
5. `/e` modifier allowing to pass Perl code/function/expression (yes, it's very powerful )

Comment: This did not work. Instead of replacing `$freebsd` with `$linux` and adding white space, it removed everything after `server.os`. There was also an unintended side effect where is changed a line below, `server.os.disabled` to `server.os` and wiped out everything after that line too.

I have no experience with perl, so I am just copying your code directly. I would prefer to use sed.

Comment: I wouldn't touch that `e` flag of GNU `sed` with a barge pole. That runs a shell and a printf for each substitution. That's also a command injection vulnerability. On the output of `printf 'server.os $freebsd\200;reboot'` for instance, that would reboot.

Comment: The first example works, but is missing a `$` in front of `linux`. I needed to add `\1\$linux` to fix it. The second is missing a `$` and if you add it in front of `linux`, it wipes out everything after `server.os`. To solve this, I had to write `\1\$ linux` - note the space between `$` and `linux`. The third example, using Perl, was also missing a `$`. To solve this, I had to write `"\$linux"`

Comment: I edited my post an hour ago to correct the mistake. My apologies. There is an error in example 1. It is missing a \ at the end of `[ \t]*\$)`. In the Perl example, there is a large gap between the `$` and `linux`. Ex: `server.os          $          linux`.

Comment: Upvoting this post because the first example answers the question. The second and third examples do replace the string correctly, but any other text on the same line after the replaced string is wiped out.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
source_txt='server.os[ \t]*$freebsd'
replace_txt=$(printf 'server.os%10s$linux')
sed -i "s/$source_txt/$replace_txt/g" ~/var/log.txt
```

`printf` is used here to create a formatted text. See [man page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) for help. It is a shell builtin and POSIX. Should work in all shells.

Comment: Better if you can add a few words, code only answers are not so encouraged

Comment: With `bash` version 3.1 or newer it's possible to avoid a subshell: `printf -v replace_txt 'server.os%10s$linux'`

Comment: This solution does work, but you should explain what is going on, as Gilles said. Also, this can be done in one line without variables.